# MBP 2017 left fan not working

Tags: macbook-pro, cooling

I have MBP 2017 (MPXT2) bought about 3 months ago.

I noticed that when it heats enough, only right fan starts blowing away hot air.
On the other hand the left side is not that hot and it is probably ok that I have never seen left fan working.
I wonder is it expected behaviour for new MPB 2017 or the left fan is probably broken?
I do not even know what can heat the left side because the GPU is built-in.

Update: Used **Macs Fan control** as suggested. It shows only one fan.

[image]

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8049553

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found some photos of disassembled MBP 2016 (13") on the internet.
Looks like there is only one fan so I should not worry.
[image]

Comment: Best possible answer.  Thanks for taking the time to research the veracity of the perceived problem rather than suggest solutions to a problem that don't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the app **Temperature Gauge** which will display the temperature of different parts of your Mac. It also gives the fan speed of all the fans.

There is also an app **Macs Fan Control** which lets you manually control the fans speed. Maybe changing fan speed will enable it to work normally if malfunctioning.

Comment: I see only one fan in *Macs Fan Control*. Looks weird because there are 2 holes on laptop's body

Comment: Please consider improving the quality of your answer by including hyperlinks to the products you've mentioned.

Comment: *Maybe changing fan speed will enable it to work normally if malfunctioning.*  How? This is like physically stepping on the accelerator to override cruise control in an attempt to fix a malfunctioning throttle. If you have a fault - *diagnose and fix!!!*

Comment: If the fan is stuck on high for some reason maybe defining a different function for fan speed will prevent this. The app I recommended allows this.  If its an internal problem it could be difficult to fix - maybe.